How to enable the Undeployed button in Tomcat console when it is disabled

How to enable the Undeployed button in Tomcat console when it is disabled. When I deploy a .war file that cannot be undeployed from the tomcat manager. Tomcat version is 8.5.16 and JVM version is 1.8. I need to enable the this undeployed button.
